# Ajax from JS to PHP (to exec sql request) then from PHP to JS

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

I'm using `$.ajax` method to pass data from my JS file to my PHP file "requetes.php". This PHP file execute SQL request depending on a variable I have on my JS file.

My Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'requetes.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    datepicker: formattedDate
  },
  success: function(data) {             
    $("#sql-results").text(data);            
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    console.log("echec de l'ajax !");
  }
})
```

In my PHP file:

```
$rq_datepicker = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM partie
    WHERE date = '"$_POST['datepicker']"'";


$query = mysqli_query($connect, $rq_datepicker);
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {  
    echo "Il y a ".$result['Reussie']." partie(s)";
    echo "Il y a ".$result['Perdue']." partie(s);"
}
```

I have reduced the code so it is easier to explain, but this works perfectly. 
I can get the "datepicker" variable from JS to PHP so I can execute my SQL request depending on this variable. 
And the line  `$("#sql-results").text(data);` return my 2 echos from my PHP file.

MY PROBLEM IS :

I just want to access those 2 variables `$result['Reussie']` & `$result['Perdue']` from my JS file.

I've tried many things like using $.ajax with method GET, or $.get, but without success..

Comment: If you want to access the two PHP values separately I'd suggest returning JSON from your PHP instead

Comment: You should return the response from php in json format and then use that on js end however you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to structure your PHP response in a way your data will be accessible in JS.
To do so, usually you use JSON, in a way that gives you data already processed and you just have to access them locally in JS.

In this case you have 2 variables which you want to access. But i guess you also want to format them into some object you have selected in jQuery afterwards.

To achieve that, there are 2 ways.

First one - do all the processing in PHP and just make variables available.

PHP side:

```
$rq_datepicker = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM partie
    WHERE date = '"$_POST['datepicker']"'";


    $query = mysqli_query($connect, $rq_datepicker);
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
            $response['dataRaw'] = array('Reussie' => $result['Reussie'],
                                     'Perdue' => $result['Perdue']);
            $response['dataProcessed'] = array('Reussie' =>  "Il y a ".$result['Reussie']." partie(s)",
                                    'Perdue' => "Il y a ".$result['Perdue']." partie(s)");
        }
    }
echo json_encode($response); // <-- using this will encode the variable according to the json specifics
```

Once the php handles the data, in JS you just have to access them in your anonymous function bind to success of the Ajax call

JS Side ( in case HTTP request goes 200 ):

```
success: function( data )
{               
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    $("#sql-results").text(response.dataProcessed.Reussie+response.dataProcessed.Perdue);
    // to access the variables instead:
    // response.dataRaw.Reussie
    // response.dataRaw.Perdue
}
```

Second one - PHP just passes variables to JS and then you build your string locally there.

PHP side:

```
$rq_datepicker = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM partie
    WHERE date = '"$_POST['datepicker']"'";


    $query = mysqli_query($connect, $rq_datepicker);
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
            $response['data'] = array('Reussie' => $result['Reussie'],
                                     'Perdue' => $result['Perdue']);
        }
    }
echo json_encode($response); // <-- using this will encode the variable according to the json specifics
```

In this case you don't have preprocessed data, so you have to build your strings locally

JS Side ( in case HTTP request goes 200 ):

```
success: function( data )
{               
    // to access the variables in this case:
    // response.data.Reussie
    // response.data.Perdue
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    var stringReussie = "Il y a "+response.data.Reussie+" partie(s)";
    var stringPerdue = "Il y a "+response.data.Perdue+" partie(s)";
    $("#sql-results").text(stringReussie+stringPerdue);
}
```

Some extra:

Using just an json_encode with an echo as output without declaring the response type, will usually set the response type to "application/json".

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

To avoid that "usually" and ensure that the content type part of the response is "application/json" ( if that's the case ), you should set the header of the response also.

```
header("Content-type:application/json")
```

Further reading about headers: [PHP Manual header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

About json_encoding, read further information here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

First things first, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you **must** use **[PDO with Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)** for query buidling.

Another thing is you just create an array with key value pair and then return that array using by encoding in json.

Example: `echo json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar'));`

and then in js code for ajax, parse the `data` using `var foo_result = JSON.parse(data['foo']);` now you can access your needed variable.

Just let me know if you achieved your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'requetes.php',
 type: 'POST',
 data: {
  datepicker: formattedDate
},
success: function(data) {             
   $("#sql-results").html(data);            
},
 error: function(xhr) {
   console.log("echec de l'ajax !");
 }
 });



$datepick = strip_tags($_POST['datepicker']);
$rq_datepicker = "
SELECT * 
FROM partie
WHERE date = '$datepick'";


$query = $connet->query($rq_datepicker);
while ($result = $query->fetch_assoc()) {  
        echo "Il y a ".$result['Reussie']." partie(s)";
        echo "Il y a ".$result['Perdue']." partie(s);"
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yey guyys it works ! Thanks a lot ! So I used this solution :

In my PHP File :

```
$response['data'] = array('Reussie' => $result['Reussie'], 'Perdue' => $result['Perdue']);
echo json_encode($response);
```

In my JS File :

```
var response = JSON.parse(data);
var stringReussie = "Il y a "+response.data.Reussie+" partie(s)";
var stringPerdue = "Il y a "+response.data.Perdue+" partie(s)";
$("#sql-results").text(stringReussie+stringPerdue);
```

I just don't understand why I couldn't put the header. Looks like it "transform" all my index.php file. But it still works so... I guess it's fine. :)

You are awesome !